# How to get url which I hit on UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

```
 NSString *testString =[NSString stringWithFormat:@" <a href = \\\\ \"www.google.com\">Google</a>"];
[webView loadHTMLString:testString baseURL:nil];
```

I want to get the URL when I click on this UIWebView content in

```
-(BOOL) webView:(UIWebView *)inWeb shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)inRequest navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)inType {

if ( inType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked ) {
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:inRequest.mainDocumentURL];
    return NO;
}

return YES;
```

}

delegate method.
When I click google hyperlink in webview it gives

> URL: applewebdata://

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is not very clear if you want to get the tapped url on webview or the webview's loaded page url ,

1. If you want to get webview loaded page url you can use NSURLRequestObject,something like

   `NSString * url = [request URL];`
2. If you want to get the clicked link url , you will have to use this java script

   `NSString *url = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location"];`

Comment: I want the second one but i print url.the url gives '<object returned empty description>'.

Comment: How have you used this , inside a tap event ? 
Just to assure that webview interaction is enabled .

Comment: i am creating uiwebview dynamically ad set its delegates.

Comment: You can try this code inside this method 
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;

Comment: NSString *url = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"window.location"];

Put this code inside this

- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;

Comment: it return @"" when i click on hyperlink.

Comment: Added new answer ,take a look .

Comment: @AbhinandanSahgal that's not how this works you shouldn't be telling people to upvote your answer whether it helped or not. I purposely avoid upvoting answers where the user has told me to do so. And I just realised the answer I've already commented on below is yours as well so -1 for trying to gain double points.

Answer (score 1):

**you can do like this way**

```
-(BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
    if ([request.URL.absoluteString rangeOfString:@"www.google.com"].location!=NSNotFound)
    {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:request.URL];
        return NO;
    }
 return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift:**

Whenever your webpage is loaded you can use this, I use it for a label in this case:

```
webUrlLabel.text = webView.request.URL.absoluteString
```

**For Objective-C:**

```
NSString *currentPage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", webView.request.URL.absoluteString];
```

`webUrlLabel` is a UILabel

`webView` is my UIWebView

Comment: According to http://www.raywenderlich.com/76735/using-nsurlprotocol-swift it should be `webView.request.URL.absoluteString`

Comment: In all honesty I was questioning myself whether I was wrong. I don't do that much swift but as far as I knew that hadn't changed so I had to do a little search before hand.

Answer (score 0):

You already have NSURLRequest object. Access url from that.

```
inRequest.URL
```

way 1:

```
NSString *currentURL = myWebView.request.URL.absoluteString;
```

Way 2:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
//CAPTURE USER LINK-CLICK.
  NSURL *url = [request URL];
  yourTextBox.text =   [url absoluteString];


  return YES;
```

}

Please let me know if it works. Thanks

Comment: I printed it. it gives 'applewebdata://'

Comment: In way 2 i print [url absoluteString] and it gives 'applewebdata://'