# Value of type 'URLRequest' has no member 'URLString'

Tags: ios, swift

I Update old app to swift 3 and I have some migration errors. 
on this part of code :

```
func done(_ request: URLRequest?, response: HTTPURLResponse?) {
    let visibleCells = tableView.visibleCells as! [NewsStoryCell]
    let cells = visibleCells.filter({ $0.news.thumbUrl == request?.URLString })

    if let cell = cells.first {
        cell.reloadThumbImage()
    }
}
```

I have error:

> Value of type 'URLRequest' has no member 'URLString'

on:

`$0.news.thumbUrl == request?.URLString`

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500128/nsurlrequest-does-not-have-a-member-named-url-swift) can be helpful

Answer (score 7):

It has indeed been changed in Swift 3

```
$0.news.thumbUrl = request?.url?.absoluteString
```